# How to pass inner objects in Thymeleaf by submit?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a page in which there are the main object and list of subobjects. When filling values and submitting the form the main object returns valid values and the list of subobjects returns as null.

```
//html
<form method="POST" th:object="${main}"  th:action="@{/submitPostAction}">
<div th:each="filter, _indx : *{subobjects}">
//Controller
@PostMapping("/submitPostAction")
public String actionSubmit(ModelMap model, MainObject mainObject){
   mainObject.getSubObjects() // is null!
   ...
}
```

Comment: What kind of **subobjects** they exactly are.? I mean what kind of of object's list you're trying to get on controller, is it a Html select-option, checkbox, textbox ?

Comment: It was a pojo bean with some amount of simple types (String, Integer, Boolean).

Comment: I mean on your HTML page , from where you’re trying to send the object. What kind of HTML element is it , is it a input type Or select option or some other .!